# How to Change Orientation of Single Paragraph or Page using Open XML and C#?

Tags: c#, openxml, export-to-word

I am generating a word document using C# and Open XML SDK. I want to change the orientation of some paragraphs and their containing pages to landscape while keeping the other ones in portrait orientation.

I tried some solutions, but they didn't achieve what I am looking for and instead the orientation of all the pages have been changed to landscape except the first one. These solutions include:

- Adding SectionProperties to the paragraph that I want to change
   its orientation to landscape:

```
WordprocessingDocument WordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ReportFile, true)
Paragraph paragraph =  new Paragraph(new ParagraphProperties(
               new SectionProperties( new PageSize() 
               { Width = (UInt32Value)15840U, Height = (UInt32Value)12240U, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape })));
WordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(paragraph);
```

- Adding a new Body to the main document and appending the paragraph to it:

```
WordprocessingDocument WordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ReportFile, true)    
Body body = new Body();          
Paragraph paragraph =  new Paragraph(new ParagraphProperties(
               new SectionProperties( new PageSize() 
               { Width = (UInt32Value)15840U, Height = (UInt32Value)12240U, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape })));
body.Append(paragraph);
WordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Append(body);
```

- Adding a new Body to the main document and appending SectionProprties to it directly:

```
WordprocessingDocument WordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ReportFile, true)  
Body body = new Body();
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
SectionProperties sectionProp = new SectionProperties(new PageSize() { Width = (UInt32Value)15840U, Height = (UInt32Value)12240U, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape });
body.Append(paragraph);
body.Append(sectionProp);
WordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Append(body);
```

So, is there a way for changing the orientation of a single paragraph/page?

Comment: I doubt, if you can change the orientation of a single paragraph using MS Office Word (application) itself?

Comment: You can do it in MS Office Word using custom margins. Check this link http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/how_to_use_different_page_orientations_inside_one_document.html

Comment: OK I checked. But it inserts the section breaks before and after the selected text also. So for example 3 paragraphs with one landscape and others in portrait mode will make upon 3 pages of the document. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. I wanna use either the Selected Text option or the Selected Section one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put a next page section break to begin a new section, and set the orientation for that section. Once you are done, start a new section with the default page orientation.

Next page Section Break to start landscape orientation:

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(
    new Paragraph(
        new ParagraphProperties(
            new SectionProperties(
                new PageSize() { Width = (UInt32Value)12240U, Height = (UInt32Value)15840U, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape },
                new PageMargin() { Top = 720, Right = Convert.ToUInt32(rightmargin * 1440.0), Bottom = 360, Left = Convert.ToUInt32(leftmargin * 1440.0), Header = (UInt32Value)450U, Footer = (UInt32Value)720U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U }))));
```

Next page Section Break to start portrait orientation:

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(
    new Paragraph(
        new ParagraphProperties(
            new SectionProperties(
                new PageSize() { Width = (UInt32Value)12240U, Height = (UInt32Value)15840U },
                new PageMargin() { Top = 720, Right = Convert.ToUInt32(rightmargin * 1440.0), Bottom = 360, Left = Convert.ToUInt32(leftmargin * 1440.0), Header = (UInt32Value)450U, Footer = (UInt32Value)720U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U }))));
```

Answer (score 4):

Based upon the above conversation and my understanding, the code might look something like below.

In Main method calling sub methods:

```
            using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filePath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                package.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document();
                Body body = package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = new Body();

                Paragraph para1 = CreatePara1(); // Paragraph 1 Portrait

                Paragraph breakBefore = CreateBreakBefore(); // Break before next paragraph that would be landscape

                Paragraph para2 = CreatePara2(); // Paragraph 2 Landscape

                Paragraph breakAfter = CreateBreakAfter(); // Break after previous paragraph that was landscape

                Paragraph para3 = CreatePara3(); // Paragraph 3 Portrait again

                body.Append(para1);
                body.Append(breakBefore);
                body.Append(para2);
                body.Append(breakAfter);
                body.Append(para3);
            }
```

Follows sub methods:

```
    private static Paragraph CreatePara1()
    {
        Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph();
        Run run1 = new Run(new Text("This is Paragraph one."));
        para1.Append(run1);
        return para1;
    }

    private static Paragraph CreateBreakBefore()
    {
        Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00BA2F0F", RsidParagraphProperties = "00BA2F0F", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00BA2F0F" };

        ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();

        SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties() { RsidR = "00BA2F0F" };
        PageSize pageSize1 = new PageSize() { Width = (UInt32Value)12240U, Height = (UInt32Value)15840U };
        PageMargin pageMargin1 = new PageMargin() { Top = 1440, Right = (UInt32Value)1440U, Bottom = 1440, Left = (UInt32Value)1440U, Header = (UInt32Value)720U, Footer = (UInt32Value)720U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U };
        Columns columns1 = new Columns() { Space = "720" };
        DocGrid docGrid1 = new DocGrid() { LinePitch = 360 };

        sectionProperties1.Append(pageSize1);
        sectionProperties1.Append(pageMargin1);
        sectionProperties1.Append(columns1);
        sectionProperties1.Append(docGrid1);

        paragraphProperties1.Append(sectionProperties1);

        paragraph2.Append(paragraphProperties1);
        return paragraph2;
    }

    private static Paragraph CreatePara2()
    {
        Paragraph para2 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00BA2F0F", RsidParagraphProperties = "00BA2F0F", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00BA2F0F" };
        BookmarkStart bookmarkStart1 = new BookmarkStart() { Name = "_GoBack", Id = "0" };

        Run run2 = new Run();
        LastRenderedPageBreak lastRenderedPageBreak1 = new LastRenderedPageBreak();
        Text text2 = new Text();
        text2.Text = "This is the paragraph two";

        run2.Append(lastRenderedPageBreak1);
        run2.Append(text2);

        para2.Append(bookmarkStart1);
        para2.Append(run2);
        BookmarkEnd bookmarkEnd1 = new BookmarkEnd() { Id = "0" };
        return para2;
    }

    private static Paragraph CreateBreakAfter()
    {
        Paragraph paragraph4 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00BA2F0F", RsidParagraphProperties = "00BA2F0F", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00BA2F0F" };

        ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties2 = new ParagraphProperties();

        SectionProperties sectionProperties2 = new SectionProperties() { RsidR = "00BA2F0F", RsidSect = "00BA2F0F" };
        PageSize pageSize2 = new PageSize() { Width = (UInt32Value)15840U, Height = (UInt32Value)12240U, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape };
        PageMargin pageMargin2 = new PageMargin() { Top = 1440, Right = (UInt32Value)1440U, Bottom = 1440, Left = (UInt32Value)1440U, Header = (UInt32Value)720U, Footer = (UInt32Value)720U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U };
        Columns columns2 = new Columns() { Space = "720" };
        DocGrid docGrid2 = new DocGrid() { LinePitch = 360 };

        sectionProperties2.Append(pageSize2);
        sectionProperties2.Append(pageMargin2);
        sectionProperties2.Append(columns2);
        sectionProperties2.Append(docGrid2);

        paragraphProperties2.Append(sectionProperties2);

        paragraph4.Append(paragraphProperties2);
        return paragraph4;
    }

    private static Paragraph CreatePara3()
    {
        Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph();
        Run run3 = new Run(new Text("This is Paragraph three."));
        para3.Append(run3);
        return para3;
    }
```

Comment: The sample code above assigns landscape orientation in CreateBreakAfter() method. So first the paragraph is added then the orientation is set in another paragraph right after. Just to be clear to help others.